# Facebook Webhook Unsubscribe page like events

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have set up Facebook realtime notification on one of my pages. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks

I have subscribed to **feed** in **page** object.
I noted that almost 90% of traffic is from like events on the page and rest 10% is from comment, posts on that page. 
Is there a way I can subscribe only to receive a page's comments/posts and not likes so as to reduce traffic coming to my endpoint ?

Comment: did u get any solution?